# What are available "Additional Metadata" keys in ARC welder

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I'm looking for the reference documentation for the "Additional Metadata" field in ARC Welder.

Here and there (also on SO) I can see answers mentioning specific keys (such as `resize`, `formFactor`, `enableExternalDirectory`, `usePlayServices`) but no reference to documentation. Is there any?

Comment: That definitions.json seems like most of the answer.  Maybe you should remove the Edit and post it as an answer for now?  I would've upvoted it personally.  It didn't get me closer to my related post about designing for ARC Welder formFactor since there aren't any soft buttons in the converted apk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528670/create-android-studio-emulators-to-match-arc-welder-formfactor  I was hoping to find a "showSoftButtonKeys" or something that would add the home/back button to the arc welder app to simulate common devices, but no luck

Comment: @whyoz thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through arc source code best I could find: https://chromium.googlesource.com/arc/arc/+/master/src/build/metadata/definitions.json which lists all the keys with some basic one-line help. I think this was previously used in the ARC Welder UI, but still hoping there is a bit more to the doc.